# google maps javascript is fetching the route but not the json api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have stumbled upon this: when I use `directionsDisplay.getDirections()` API to fetch and display the results, it works, but when I do it via json:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJR0FT51wiDogRNuVKiLn9ZLA&destination=place_id:ChIJMWaiY0YpTIYRRdGvCMg7m0g&key=MY_KEY&waypoints=via:place_id:ChIJaWS37r88DIgRu-ak1l7eXAQ`

I get `"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"`

I am wondering why this might be happening? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "via:" keyword from the waypoints to get the response.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJR0FT51wiDogRNuVKiLn9ZLA&destination=place_id:ChIJMWaiY0YpTIYRRdGvCMg7m0g&key=MY_KEY&waypoints=place_id:ChIJaWS37r88DIgRu-ak1l7eXAQ
```

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints):

> The via: prefix is most effective when creating routes in response to the user dragging the waypoints on the map. Doing so allows the user to see how the final route may look in real-time and helps ensure that waypoints are placed in locations that are accessible to the Google Maps Directions API.
>
> **Caution:** Using the via: prefix to avoid stopovers results in directions that are very strict in their interpretation of the waypoint. **This may result in** severe detours on the route or **ZERO_RESULTS in the response status code if the Google Maps Directions API is unable to create directions through that point**.